# mysqli fetch_assoc only 1 result instead of all

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch

```
if ($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tab WHERE ID = $id")) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
echo "ID:". $row['ID'];
echo "Product:" .$row['Product'];
... }
$result->close();
} else {
echo "could not retrieve data from db";  }
```

I only get one result, but it should be a lot more. 
How do I get all the results?

btw I cannot use fetch_all.

Comment: Are you sure you should get more results?  Your WHERE clause references what I expect to be your PK, and there can only be one.  Have you tried the query directly on the MySQL command line or MyPHPAdmin?

Comment: You really need to be careful when putting user data into your queries by always [properly escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Seeing `$id` in the query string is very, very bad, especially when mysqli supports `bind_param` to set these.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an ID in your query, that means that you are asking for a specific item. In order to select all you have to remove this condition.

Your code would look like:

```
  if ($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tab")) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
      echo "ID:". $row['ID'];
      echo "Product:" .$row['Product'];
    }
    $result->close();
  } else {
    echo "There is no data in the database";  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tab WHERE ID = $id"
```

with

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tab WHERE ID = $id LIMIT 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must select both id and product from tab and also add a where statement.

Your code would look like:

```
  if ($result = $db->query("SELECT ID, Product, user FROM tab WHERE user='".$username."' ")) { //$username = john;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
      echo "ID:". $row['ID'];
      echo "Product:" .$row['Product'];
    }



  } else {
    echo "There is no data in the database"; 

  } result->close();
```

Let me hope your equate value is the name john it may be anything. so you will get all result rows from the database where the word john is listed.

put $username = 'john';  before the if statement.

Answer (score -2):

The process of fetching data from a MYSQL result goes like this:

- Connect to the host
- Select the DB
- Run the query

`if ($result) //Check if the return is true`

`while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {`
`// do something with the $row`
`//like print it`
`}`
`}`

In order to make fully sure print the query using

```
echo $your_query
```

Then run that query through phpMyAdmin and see what results or error you get.